# Is there any way to track links on web view of a newsletter email?

Tags: outbound-email

I am able to track links on email but I have a requirement to track links also on web view of an email. I have seen documentation but could'nt find any solution. Please help me to get this functionality.
   Your help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid it's not possible in Outbound E-mail. You could, of course, track it yourself then, but there's also no way to add the data to the existing statistics for a Mailing.

A crazy idea would be if you could somehow generate this web view based on each generated e-mail, before it is sent to each Contact, but after it has been generated by the Mailer service -- since the links there would point to the website anyway and track the right data. But how would you even make that manageable?

In short, you may want to reevaluate the feasibility of that requirement.